# How to use regex expression for letters numbers and alphanumeric characters

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, regex-group

Can anyone help me with my regex expression. Im trying to validate the date string as follows 27 August 1979 - 05:25 am can anyone help me to fix my code by using uppercase lowercase hyphen, colon text and numbers.

Code

```
regula.custom({
    name:'AlphaSpecial',
    defaultMessage: "The text field can only contain letters,numbers and alphanumeric characters!",
    validator:function(){
        return /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.:-]*$/.test(this.value)
    }
})
```

Comment: Looks like you just need to add a whitespace pattern, `\s`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try matching ^\w+\s\d{4}\s-\s\d{2}:\d{2}\s\w{2}$

To learn more about regex I would recommend using https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

And to test your regex this site is great: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest for dates (with months in english)

```
^([012]?\d|3[01])\s[JFMASOND][a-z]{2,}\s(\d{2}|\d{4})\s-\s([01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d$
```

**([012]?\d|3[01])** = digit(s) for the day 01 or 1 to 31

**\s** = space

**[JFMASOND]** = Begin the month with uppercase.

**[a-z]{2,}** = At least 2 more characters in lowercase (this part can be improved).

**\s** = space.

**(\d{2}|\d{4})** = Year with 2 or 4 digits.

**\s-\s** = space + hyphen + space

**([01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d** = hour (00:00 to 23:59)